# How to modify project admins group using TFS process template?

Tags: tfs

I have almost 400 projects to create in my TFS project collection in TFS 2017. I don't want to have to create and configure each project, one at a time. I'd like to create a custom process template, which seems easy enough to do, but I can't find how to add an AD group to the Project Administrators group.

The GroupsandPermissions.xml file allows the creation of new groups but doesn't accept the Project Administrators group as an option.  I've read here where others have tested it.  Also the macro for project administrators is reported not to work because the group already exists.

Any ideas how to add an AD group to project administrators in the process template or otherwise?